# Bing API Azure Marketplace: how to know whether there are more results?

Tags: bing-api

I am using the *Bing Search API in Windows Azure Marketplace* (i.e., the API that replaces the old Bing 2.0 API, that expires on 1st August 2012). The [Migration Guide](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=migration%20guide%20bing&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://www.bing.com/webmaster/content/developers/ADM_MIGRATION_GUIDE.docx&ei=JGURUJjDO4WM4gSo2IDYAw&usg=AFQjCNGb51AqhxLDxCqHgUDymDuoNYFzVQ) provided by Microsoft states:

> If there are no more pages of results, the `/feed/link[@rel=’next’]` property will no longer appear [...].

However, it seems that this is not always the case. For example, a News query for `"Roger Federer"` does not contain a `link` element:

**Request:** [https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27"Roger+Federer"%27](https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27Roger%20Federer%27)

**Response:**

```xml
<feed xmlns:base="https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">"Roger Federer"</title>
    <subtitle type="text">Bing News Search</subtitle>
    <id>https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News?Query='"Roger Federer"'</id>
    <rights type="text"/>
    <updated>2012-07-26T15:43:03Z</updated>
    <entry>
        <!-- ... -->
    </entry>
    <!-- ... -->
</feed>
```

Nevertheless, there are more news: [https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27"Roger+Federer"%27&$skip=50](https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/News?Query=%27Roger%20Federer%27&%24skip=50)

Does anybody know where the problem might be? (Or where there is reliable documentation for the API?)

Comment: I thought that providing the $skip=0 query parameter would solve the problem. Unfortunately, it does not do so always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this anymore: the response now contains a `link` element.

I suppose the Bing guys have fixed the problem in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do is to update your BingSearchContainer.cs - I found there was an older version when I first started using it that caused me all sorts of problems like this.  When I updated a lot of things started working.

I think the problem is that the BingSearchContainer is "fixing" your query and messing you up.  Try the following:

Then try to do the query without the " marks.  It will probably succeed and return results.

Try to use ' instead, you will probably get some results.

I think the container is escaping all your queries as a single phrase match by default.  So just adding a search will work.  Now when you really do have two phrases you need to search for...  That I can't get working yet either.

Comment: Thanks, Jason, for your input. I do not see where BingSearchContainer.cs comes in — the problem already shows up in the results of the web requests themselves (see URLs above). IIUC, BingSearchContainer.cs is not involved in this.